# How to create multi-region SaaS with isolated data

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture

can someone help me with the right architecture of an application? Our application is currently hosted in the USA, but we have clients in Europe. We are launching new data residency for the EU region. For handle requests, we can simply use routing with subdomain or path ( eu.example.com or example.com/eu ) for region detection. Data will not be shared between regions.

How can we make our current mobile application or third-party services like Zapier compatible with this?

Solution what we have currently that we can have a single endpoint for this type of request. And on this endpoint, we have a table with user->region association in the database or file. Based on this information, we proxying requests to the right region API, but we not sure this solution follows GDPR requirements.

The main question is: How to handle requests from services where we can't predefine the user's region with follows GDPR requirements?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Just to clarify - also an engineer here - so you should still absolutely do your legal compliance investigation and work.*

This is hard problem - with a not-so-hard solution. It's just that, that solution is often missed because **we are often too focused on getting EU traffic compliant with GDPR without causing a bad user experience.** For everyone.

1. Use appropriate country detection mechanisms, don't rely on the URL entirely. (mentioned as country telemetry in the next item)
2. Ask the user. See if your country telemetry is matching with what they are saying in terms of where they are registered from. See it across the board, until you are confident that you can near-deterministically say where they are - which data center they belong to.
3. Most importantly: don't design for EU+GDPR separately. Design for everyone and give them the same options (which covers GDPR), same level of transparency, export capabilities, delete capabilities etc...With changing regulations, you'll never be on top of all of those requirements separately, so try to go collectively as much as you can. This is only going to make your app better. Yes - you'll host the data in elsewhere, but everything else - functionality-wise, what your users can ask from you, should be the same.
4. Read the data transfer regulations.